# What is the easiest/ computationally efficient way to find the indexes at particular locations?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, unique

I have a matrix

```
m =

 2     2     1
 3     2     1
 0     4     1
 0     4     1
 5     4     1
 0     5     2
 1     2     2
 1     3     2
 1     4     2
 1     1     3
 0     2     3
 0     3     4
 0     3     4
```

that is potentially of N x 3, where N can be very large.

I want to find the index in the first column (1-13) where i have zeros but only if there are duplicate rows or the rows are unique. I don't want rows that the 2nd and 3rd column are the same but the first column is other than zero. In other words, if there is a zero at the first column but its corresponding number in the second and third column are the same with another one that has a different number other than zero in the first column, then ignore the index of that zero.   So, in the example above, i want to return only the indices 6, 11,12, 13. Index 3,4 should not be return because they violate the rule that there is a row similar to that (2nd and 3rd column) but the first column is different, as we can see below:

```
 0     4     1
 0     4     1
 5     4     1
```

One slow solution would be to find the indices of the rows that the first column is 0 `indm=m(:,1)==0` and then iterate over the rows of the matrix checking whether any other row exists in  matrix (`m`) that has identical 2nd and 3rd columns but different 1st column. If such case does not exist then add the index of the row to the list to be returned by the program. 
However, this method, would require "for loops" going over large matrices.

Comment: Does the order of the rows matter, i.e. if row 5 was at the very end of the list, would rows 3,4 count as good?

Comment: no. the order doesn't really matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this (assuming that a row is bad if there is any other row with the same columns 2 and 3) is to find all the different rows, and then checking whether the first column is the same everywhere.

```
%# uIdx is the same for sets of rows where m(i,2:3) is equal
[~,~,uIdx] = unique(m(:,2:3),'rows');
%# allZeros is true if all entries in the first column of m
%# corresponding to a set are the zero 
allZeros = accumarray(uIdx,m(:,1),[],@(x)all(x==0)); 

%# a good row belongs to a set of rows from m(:,2:3)
%# where all corresponding entries in the first column are zeros
%# use allZeros(uIdx) to expand allZeros to size(m,1)
goodRowIndices = find(allZeros(uIdx) == true)

goodRowIndices =

     6
    11
    12
    13
```

Comment: I don't have the function `range` on my Matlab. What is this function?

Comment: I make small modifications: `allTheSame = accumarray(uIdx,m(:,1)) == 0; ` and then `goodRowIndices = find(allTheSame(uIdx));`. I think it should be equivalent. IMO, way better than my solution!

Comment: can you explain me a bit more the solution please? I am not familiar with accumarray.

Comment: @JustCurious: the third output of unique returns "group numbers", i.e. ones, twos, threes, for the first, second, third unique set of rows in columns 2 and 3 of your array. the `range` function (which is equivalent to @(x)max(x)-min(x) is 0 if all entries are similar. `accumarray` is a useful Matlab function that applies a function (e.g. @range) to all the values of the second input that are grouped by the first input, i.e. the first element of the output is the function applied to all elements of the second input where the first input equals 1.

Comment: @Bentoy13: good point, since all entries have to be 0, it's possible to simplify. The sum, as you propose, will work with `accumarray`, but I use `all(x==0)` for a bit more readability (and to account for the possibility that there may be negative entries in `m(:,1)`

Comment: @Jonas Indeed, it's more general now while keeping the complexity low.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
mm = m(:,1)==0;
imm = find(mm);
[mu,~, imu] = unique(m(mm,2:3),'rows','stable');
[~,ia] = setdiff(mu,m(~mm,2:3),'rows');
X = imm(ismember(imu,ia));
```

Line 3 extract the unique lines beginning with 0; line 4 keeps only the lines that does not appear in the lines not beginning by 0, and line 5 get back the indexes of the lines  to keep.

Not sure its the most efficient way, because of it involves two sorts.

Comment: i get and Index exceeds matrix dimensions error. Does it work for you?

Comment: This seems to be the "cleanest" solution. Great coding

Comment: Elapsed time is 0.343366 seconds. @Jonas solution: Elapsed time is 0.088097 seconds. But as i am not confident with Jonas solutions i was wondering whether they are doing the same thing...

Comment: @JustCurious They are doing the same thing, his way is more optimized.